# Baye's Theorem, conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

You are dealt three cards. The events of interest concern the number of face cards that you are dealt ($0,1,2,$ or $3$).  Construct a tree diagram tracking face cards.

> d) What is the conditional probability that you are dealt three face cards given that you are dealt at least two face cards.

The answer is $.07692$, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  I don't see how it's not $0.0095$

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.

Comment: It *is* about $0.07692$.

Comment: As you have figured it out, maybe you'd like to write it up and post it as an answer. Then after a while you can accept it. This helps clear the site of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster has not written up the answer, I'll expand it here in case anyone else lands on this question.

In theory, the conditional probability $P(A|B)$, that of event $A$ happening given that event $B$ already occurred, is:
$$
\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
In English, "A given B" means we want to know the probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening if $B$ already happened. The probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening is ${P(A \cap B)}$ and the universe is the set of all events in which $B$ has happened, so our denominator is not 1, but $P(B)$.

Specifically, in a standard poker deck of 52 cards (no jokers) there are 12 face cards and 40 non-face cards. The probability we want is the number of ways to get 3 face cards—$P(A \cap B)$—divided by the number of ways to get at least two face cards—$P(B)$.

The number of ways to get three face cards is:
$$
{12 \choose 3}\cdot{40 \choose 0} = 220
$$
The number of ways to get *at least* two face cards is the number of ways to get two face cards **and** the number of ways to get three face cards. This is:
$$
{12 \choose 2}\cdot{40 \choose 1} + {12 \choose 3}\cdot{40 \choose 0} = 2640 + 220 = 2860
$$

So the answer is $\frac{220}{2860} \approx 0.076923$ as stated above.

Comment: It should be $P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @hejseb Yup, obviously. Must have had a brain freeze; thanks for catching that!